# Mono for Android - How to disabled Home button

Tags: button, mono, xamarin.android

When my activity is running, I don't want return in home screen when I click on Home button.

I find answers for android but I do not manage to translate code to mono.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the home button is an anti-pattern and generally frowned upon in Android. You are not able to override the behavior of the Home button itself in ICS and up either. However if you are developing a Kiosk mode app or a Home launcher, it is possible to work it around.

You will need to tell Android that your application is a Launcher/Home application. Beyond creating a custom home app, there is no way to intercept the HOME button except through firmware modifications.

Comment: I know that disable is anti-pattern but this is what I must do.
Generaly I don't justify why I need this function or other function. The tablet will use by customers and the shopkeeper don't want everybody ferret about it.
So I want to prevent intrusion. Indeed there are tools that turn my application into launcher-Home application but I wanted code. It's a pity ! Thanks